RandomSearchCV and data leakage
I'm looking for the best practice to avoid data leakage. I have 1 feature that requires mode imputation. The model is XGBoost Classifier.
These are the steps that I planned:

Split data in random 80% training set - 20% test set
Apply mode imputation on training and test set independently
Execute RandomSearchCV on the training set for hyperparameter tuning
Train model on the whole training set using the best parameter set found
Evaluate model on unseen test set

Now, my doubt is: is it okay to perform the mode imputation on the whole training set and then perform RandomSearchCV? I thought that data leakage applies only when evaluating with the unseen test set.
Or should I perform the imputation in each fold of RandomSearchCV to avoid data leakage? if so, how can I do it? I saw Sklearn pipelines, but I cannot figure out how to apply the mode imputation only to the specific feature I need
Thank you in advance!
P.s. feedback on all the steps are welcome too if anything is wrong!

Note that the [ml] tag, like the description says, is for the family of programming languages (OCaml, SML, etc...). You want [machine-learning].


Apply mode imputation on training and test set independently

In general, when making predictions (including on the test set), you can have as little as one single sample. In such a case, which is perfectly permissible for the test set (unlike the training set), the model will fail to impute missing values as there's nothing to go on. So I think the more robust approach would be to fit an imputer on the training set, and use that fitted imputer to handle NaNs in the test set.
sklearn pipelines handle this naturally, as once you fit the pipeline on the training data, the fitted estimators can be seamlessly applied to any other set.

is it okay to perform the mode imputation on the whole training set and then perform RandomSearchCV? [...] Or should I perform the imputation in each fold of RandomSearchCV to avoid data leakage?

Learning the imputation after the split means that the training data can't take the validation samples into account. This keeps the validation set "unseen", so you get a more realistic measure of generalisation performance.

I cannot figure out how to apply the mode imputation only to the specific feature I need

ColumnTransformer and make_column_transformer are used to selectively apply transformations to different columns. Suppose you wanted to impute for a column named "feature_12", leaving the rest of the columns intact:
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

preprocessor = make_column_transformer(
  (SimpleImputer(strategy='mode'), ['feature_12']),
  remainder='passthrough',
)

You can chain on an estimator, and give the resulting pipeline to sklearn-compatible CV methods.
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import HistGradientBoostingRegressor

pipeline = make_pipeline(preprocessor, HistGradientBoostingRegressor())

search_results = RandomizedSearchCV(
  pipeline, ...
).fit(X, y)

The resulting pipeline:

The inner box is the column transformer, which has a left branch that imputes for the specified column, and a right branch that passes the other columns on. The regressor comes after the column transformer, operating on the imputed data.

Many thanks!
When you say "I think the more robust approach would be to fit an imputer on the training set, and use that fitted imputer to handle NaNs in the test set." Do you mean that after the RandomSearchCV, before training the model with the optimal parameter set on the whole training set, I should do:
preprocessor.fit(X_train) and then X_train_processed = preprocessor.transform(X_train) and X_test_processed = preprocessor.transform(X_test) ? Also, isn't this leading to data leakage from the train set to the test set?

No problem. I meant that the imputer should be part of the pipeline. Any time .fit() is called, whether it be within RandomizedSearchCV or when you're doing the final fit, the imputation is figured out automatically by the pipeline. You would use the search to find the optimal parameters & do a final fit on all of the training data using those optimal params. For example: best_params = RandomizedSearchCV(pipeline, ...).fit(X_trn, y_trn).best_params_, and then the final fit best_pipeline = pipeline.set_params(**best_params).fit(X_trn, y_trn). y_test = best_pipeline.predict(X_test).

Oh wow, I didn't know you could do that! Great, it worked very well, thank you a lot!

My pleasure. Glad it's working well.
